# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SYS' and 'SYS'

Tags: python, scipy, signaling

I am try to do some signal processing in Python, butI have "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: " for this code:

```
from numbers import Real#Real class:To Complex, 'Real' adds the operations 
that work on real numbers.

def as_sys(s):
    if isinstance(s,Real):
        return SYS([s],[1])
    return s

class SYS(object):
    def __init__(self,num,den):
        self.num=num
        self.den=den

    def feedback(self):#1
        return self / (self + 1)

    def __mul__(self,s):
        s=as_sys(s)
        """
        np.polymul()
        Find the product of two polynomials.
        Finds the polynomial resulting from the multiplication of the two input polynomials. 
        Each input must be either a poly1d object or a 1D sequence of polynomial coefficients, from highest to lowest degree.
        """
        num=np.polymul(self.num,s.num)
        den = np.polymul(self.den,s.den)
        return SYS(num,den)

    def __add__(self,s):
        s=as_sys(s)
        den=np.polymul(self.den,s.den)
        num=np.polyadd(np.polymul(self.num,s.den),
                  np.polymul(s.num,self.den))
        return SYS(num,den)

    def __sadd__(self,s):
        return self+s

    def __div__(self,s):
        s=as_sys(s)
        return self*SYS(s.den,s.num)

    def __iter__(self):#2
        return iter((self.num,self.den))
```

When I try to run this code:

```
M,b,k=1.0,10,20
plant=SYS([1],[M,b,k])#1

pi_settings=[(10,1e-10),(200,1e-10),
        (200,100),(50,100)]

fig,ax=pl.subplots(figsize=(8,3))

for pi_setting in pi_settings:
    pi_ctrl=SYS(pi_setting,[1,1e-6])#2
    feedback=(pi_ctrl*plant).feedback()#3

    _,x=signal.step(feedback,T=t)
    label="$K_p={:d},K_i={:3.0f}$".format(*pi_setting)
    ax.plot(t,x,label=label)

ax.legend(loc="best",ncol=2)
ax.set_xlabel(u'time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel(u'position(m)')
```

I got an error like below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-318-6657660ad435> in <module>()
      9 for pi_setting in pi_settings:
     10     pi_ctrl=SYS(pi_setting,[1,1e-6])#2
---> 11     feedback=(pi_ctrl*plant).feedback()#3
     12 
     13     _,x=signal.step(feedback,T=t)

<ipython-input-317-a24ff95d8d45> in feedback(self)
     12 
     13     def feedback(self):#1
---> 14         return self / (self + 1)
     15 
     16     def __mul__(self,s):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SYS' and 'SYS'
```

The system I used is Window 7+Python 3.5+Anaconda+Jupyter notebook.

Please help me to figure out what wrong with my code. Thank you.

Comment: What should self /( self + 1)  be?

Comment: if this is python 3; `/` looks up `__truediv__` and not `__div__`. see [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) or the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__).

Comment: Thank you. It works when I change "__div__"  to "__truediv__".